# Friedel–Crafts with unsaturated halides

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

Which of the following compounds will not undergo Friedel–Crafts reaction with benzene: vinyl chloride or allyl chloride?

According to me vinyl chloride will be a better electrophile than allyl chloride, hence allyl chloride should be the answer. Is this a correct way to see? As my answer does not match with the textbook

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/24404/friedel-crafts-alkylation-and-hybridization

Answer (score 0):

Friedel-Craft reactions only occur with alkyl halides, vinyl or aromatic halides do not react  [further information here](http://www.chem.ucalgary.ca/courses/350/Carey5th/Ch12/ch12-7b.html) so the answer is vinyl chloride.

Comment: So, acc. To you, allyl chloride do not react with benzene?

Comment: No! The opposite; vinyl chloride does not react with benzene under F-C conditions,